# Using reflection to get private fields from a hidden AOSP class

Tags: java, android, reflection

I am trying to use reflection to access a private final field from ActivityView class, which is hidden in Android AOSP. I created an ActivityView object using reflection, which has a **SurfaceView** inside, and i need to have a callback which tells me when the surface is created.

```
val activityViewClass = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityView")
val activityView = activityViewClass.getConstructor(Context::class.java).newInstance(this)
```

Then, there are two options to have access to that callback:

**1. Access directly the private final callback field from the class.**

So i try to access **mSurfaceCallback** field which throws **java.lang.NoSuchFieldException**.

`val field = activityView::class.java.getDeclaredField("mSurfaceCallback")`

If i try to access any other private field i get the same error.

If i call `activityView::class.java.declaredFields` i get an empty list.

I tried in Java, in Kotlin with **kotlin-reflect** library and no success.

I also tried https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections library for reflection, i get the same results.

**2. Set a ActivityView.StateCallback to the activity view.**

ActivityView has a StateCallback object which looks like this:

```
/** Callback that notifies when the container is ready or destroyed. */
    public abstract static class StateCallback {
        /**
         * Called when the container is ready for launching activities. Calling
         * {@link #startActivity(Intent)} prior to this callback will result in an
         * {@link IllegalStateException}.
         *
         * @see #startActivity(Intent)
         */
        public abstract void onActivityViewReady(ActivityView view);
        /**
         * Called when the container can no longer launch activities. Calling
         * {@link #startActivity(Intent)} after this callback will result in an
         * {@link IllegalStateException}.
         *
         * @see #startActivity(Intent)
         */
        public abstract void onActivityViewDestroyed(ActivityView view);
        /**
         * Called when a task is moved to the front of the stack inside the container.
         * This is a filtered version of {@link TaskStackListener}
         */
        public void onTaskMovedToFront(ActivityManager.StackInfo stackInfo) { }
    }
```

This is exactly what i need. But since it is an abstract class i cannot instantiate it. And i also cannot extend it because it is hidden.

Any ideas how to access that private field or how to extend a hidden abstract class using reflection?

Comment: Which SDK version you used?

Comment: @ihsan.gaozp I use Android 28

Comment: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces#results-of-keeping-non-sdk  plz check this doc , google has restrict reflections . but there are also some methods to workaround this .

Comment: http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/art/runtime/jni_internal.cc#88 This is how system restrict your access. So you can make your app a system app by using __android.shareduid="android.uid.system"__

Comment: Thank you so much @ihsan.gaozp. The app is a system app so i will give it a try.

Comment: I want to do exaclty the same, did you find out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

System apps can access hidden classes without doing anything. If you can access ActivityView you can also access StateCallBack.

You should define state

```
private StateCallback mStateCallback = new StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityViewReady(ActivityView view) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onActivityViewReady");
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityViewDestroyed(ActivityView view) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onActivityViewDestroyed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTaskMovedToFront(ActivityManager.StackInfo stackInfo) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onTaskMovedToFront");
            }
        };
```

and then set it like this

```
    mActivityView = findViewById(R.id.activity_view);
    mActivityView.setCallback(mStateCallback);
```

Comment: Android Studio seems it does not recognize ActivityView.StateCallback